# SQL - new query after reload page

Tags: python, sql, flask, browser

Need to create a table based on some data from MySQL, after first query, it doesn't reload in browser on every time i refresh. Is Python Flask able to perform this?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import mysql.connector
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(/**/
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute('''/**/''')

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
  print(x)

mydb.close()

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/')
def index():

    return str(myresult)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: move sql code into index() function

Comment: Thank yoy so much! It`s works!

Answer (score 0):

@themadmax, helps to do this! Thanks all

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import mysql.connector

app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/')
def index():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        /**/
        )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()

    mycursor.execute('''/**/''')

    myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

    for x in myresult:
        print(x)

    mydb.close()

    return str(myresult)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```